# How do I avoid the deletion of wrong folders? Can anyone review my batch code?

Tags: batch-file, parameters, directory, delete-file

I am new to programming and created a batch that deletes the folders (session folders) that contain .dft-files.
If there are no .dft-files, then they should not be deleted ... while testing this script I noticed that folders that did not contain a .dft got deleted.
I basically work with two parameters:
%%a stands for the user profile folder,
%%b stands for the session folder.

1. I firstly look into a folder of profiles and map-out the current user-profiles.

   DIR "D:\New folder" /a:d /b  > profiles.txt

Output example:
00001
00002
00003

2. Afterwards, I map-out how many session folders exist per user-profile.

   for /f %%a in (profiles.txt) do (
   DIR "D:\New folder\%%a\current\14_0_container" /a:d /b  > session.txt

Output example:
Session1
Session2
Session3

3. Now that I know the available user-profiles and their session folders, I need to check if they contain .dft-files.
   If I encounter a session folder with such a file, then it should be deleted.

   for /f %%b in (session.txt) do (
   echo "looking for .dft files . . .", if exist D:\New folder\%%a\current\14_0_container\%%b\drafiles*.dft 
   (RD /s /q "D:\New folder\%%a\current\14_0_container\%%b")

So, this is my code until now:

```
@echo off
DIR "D:\New folder" /a:d /b  > profiles.txt
for /f %%a in (profiles.txt) do (
DIR "D:\New folder\%%a\current\14_0_container" /a:d /b  > session.txt
for /f %%b in (session.txt) do (
echo ".dft-bestanden zoeken . . .", if exist D:\New folder\%%a\current\14_0_container\%%b\drafiles\*.dft 
(RD /s /q "D:\New folder\%%a\current\14_0_container\%%b")
)
)

echo "Done!"
cmd /k
```

**Can you see what I messed up?
I tested the script by creating another file-type and placing it in .\00001\current\14_0_container\Session1\drafiles and Session1 got deleted.**
:(

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in ("D:\New folder") do (
   for /d %%b in ("D:\New folder\%%a\current\14_0_container") do (
      if exist "%%b\*.dft" echo .dft files are in "%%b" so rd /s /q "%%b"
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: Hallo foxidrive, thank you for your answer. I tried your option but it won't even delete the folders. The code looks like this now: @echo off
for /d %%a in ("C:\tst") do (
   for /d %%b in ("C:\tst\%%a\current\14_0_container") do (
      if exist "C:\tst\%%a\current\14_0_container\%%b\drafiles\*.dft" (rd /s /q "C:\tst\%%a\current\14_0_container\%%b")
   )
)
echo "Done!"
pause                             

Any suggestions?

Comment: It has an `echo` command so you can test it before removing the `echo .dft files are in "%%b" so` part.  What did it show on the screen?

Comment: It ran the script without stopping and showed Done!, as expected. I will try it again soon.

Comment: My script doesn't have `done` in it.  Your script in the comment above isn't anything like the script I provided,